# Can't build for android on Mac with buildozer

Tags: python, android, buildozer

I wrote a program in python and wrote a .kv file and I can run it and it works properly. But when I want to build it for android using buildozer after navigating to the working directory and typing `buildozer init` and then in the spec file adding the icon and the presplash, after that i write `buildozer -v android debug`. Then it types different things. Few things I think might be important are: `/bin/sh: dpkg: command not found`,

and after that:

```
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a 
bug report
Exception in thread background thread for pid 89524:
```

And what's probably most important:

```
STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking for python3.8... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for g++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a             
bug report


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py",     
line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", 
line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
```

android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1294, in 
main()
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 728, in **init**
getattr(self, command)(args)
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 151, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 210, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 596, in build_recipes
recipe.build_arch(arch)
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/recipes/hostpython3/**init**.py", line 95, in build_arch
shprint(sh.Command(join(recipe_build_dir, 'configure')))
File "/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-
android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
for line in output:
File "/Users/grzesiek/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sh.py", line 953,
in next
self.wait()
File "/Users/grzesiek/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sh.py", line 879,
in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/Users/grzesiek/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/sh.py", line 905,
in handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

```
  RAN: /Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64- 
v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/configure

  STDOUT:
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
checking for python3.8... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for g++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
configure: error: internal configure error for the platform triplet, please file a     
bug report


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m     
pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=kalkulator --bootstrap=sdl2 -- 
requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs -- 
color=always --storage- 
dir="/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/kalkulator/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64- 
v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
    # ENVIRONMENT:
#     TMPDIR = '/var/folders/l_/g3zlw0w55nbc9k1v110rn0gh0000gn/T/'
#     __CFBundleIdentifier = 'com.apple.Terminal'
#     XPC_FLAGS = '0x0'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     DISPLAY = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.RArnFLp29W/org.xquartz:0'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.FmVNzY5SpB/Listeners'
#     XPC_SERVICE_NAME = '0'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'Apple_Terminal'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '444'
#     TERM_SESSION_ID = '79D90C22-EBBE-40E7-A4E4-7F76B66B2457'
#     SHELL = '/bin/zsh'
#     HOME = '/Users/grzesiek'
#     LOGNAME = 'grzesiek'
#     USER = 'grzesiek'
#     PATH = '/Users/grzesiek/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-
```

1.9.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/grzesiek/bin:/Users/gr
zesiek/Library/Python/3.9/bin'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PWD = '/Users/grzesiek/Desktop/Kalkulator'
#     OLDPWD = '/Users/grzesiek/Desktop'
#     LANG = 'pl_PL.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/Users/grzesiek/Library/Python/3.9/bin/buildozer'
#     __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0x1D:0x2A'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/Users/grzesiek/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/Users/grzesiek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/Users/grzesiek/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

I'm aware of that, that it's a miserable way of showing what I got. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk0MeJ7YIMc Can any one help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was having this issue as well. This post seemed to fix it for me.

https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2568

Basically just try adding this to the requirements in your buildozer.spec file.

```
    requirements = python3==3.9.12,hostpython3==3.9.12
```

Comment: Now I get this end of STDERR:# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

Comment: Using this line in spec file: requirements = python3==3.9.0,kivy,hostpython3==3.9.0

Comment: Life savers! Had python3==3.9,hostpython3==3.9 and was getting this error constantly!